# How to fetch data from two tables based on session variable php?

Tags: php, mysql, session

Actually im trying to display data from 2 tables on database based on current session, basically, i had read many article and forum on how to solve this problem but i still facing them till now. so those are data and code that already i did:

```
<?php
include('db.php');

$sql="SELECT*
FROM users
INNER JOIN details ON users.id= details.id LIMIT 1 WHERE users.id ='$loggedin_id' " ;

$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
if (!$result) {
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($db));
exit();
}
?>
```

so here, i got this error:
"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE users.id = '16'' at line 3". so if i only use this query:

```
 $sql="SELECT* FROM users INNER JOIN details ON users.id= details.id"
```

it will display all data in my database, but i only need data from current session.

here is my session.php file:

```
<?php 
include('db.php');
session_start();
$user_check=$_SESSION['sess_username'];
$ses_sql=mysqli_query($db,"select username,id from users where username='$user_check' ");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$loggedin_session=$row['username'];
$loggedin_id=$row['id'];
$role = $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
if(!isset($loggedin_session) && $role!="user"){
  header('Location: index.php?err=2');
}
?>
```

this is my tables detail:
[table users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t30Nw.png)
[table details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XteFW.png)

hope someone can help me, im new with my sql and php. tq

Comment: Your query is malformed... i think.. LIMIT before WHERE. I think you need a subquery. some mysql wiz can help you out.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman thanks for your advise. :')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your query like that.

```
$sql="SELECT*
FROM users
INNER JOIN details ON users.id= details.id WHERE users.id ='$loggedin_id' LIMIT 1" ;
```

Comment: Great keep it up. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think your query should be like below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users
INNER JOIN details ON users.id= details.id  WHERE users.id = $loggedin_id ";
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not run my query but   this work fine , $sql = "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN details ON users.id= details.id  WHERE users.id = $loggedin_id ";

Comment: tq... i think this work too,, need to explore further

Answer (score -1):

You can neglect the INNER JOIN and Use Procedural Steps as follows:

- Step 1: Just Start Session in all your pages- session_start();
- Step 2: In your Db create a column for Session e.g sessionCheck
- Step 3: On the Sign-up page start session and use MySqli last insert
  function like:

`$_session["anything"] = mysqli_insert_id(your db connection variable);` 
then store this session Id to a variable (like - `$sessionCheck = $_session["anything"];` Insert the value of this variable to all the column in your Database on the session column as you perform insert. Let the session column by int and unique.

- Step 4: On the Display Page use control structure specifically Nested
  IF instead of INNER JOIN.
- STEP 5: ALL your Insertion insert the value of $_sessionCheck into
  sessionCheck in all your tables except the sign-up page (because the
  session id is originally picked from sign-up page so you don't need
  to insert into sign up again)
- Step6: All your Select should be tie to `WHERE sessionCheck = $sessionCheck`

This works perfectly well for me on my Procedural PHP 7 (MySqli) and MySQL 5